# Natural Text Editing is not working in iTerm2

Tags: terminal, keyboard, bash, iterm

I've seen dozens of articles that talk about making terminal life better by switching to iTerm2 and then turning on "Natural Text Editing" under Profile > Keys. Then you can use the normal `option`+left/right to move between words.

I have tried that, and it works.. One time. I can jump back exactly one word, and then I just get a bell any time I try moving left or right with `option`. If I hit enter, the command works as expected. And at the next prompt I'm allowed to cursor over one word and then it stops again.

I have tried the same in the default Terminal app and get the same results. I can move one word, and then bells.

In playing around with the keys, after `option`+`left arrow` the one time, I can still move around normally with the left and right cursor arrows. But I seem to be in some weird vim-like shortcut mode as hitting `b` moves me back and `w` moves me forward. Typing `v` puts me in a vim-like editor (`:q` to get back to the command prompt.

This is on a brand new M1 Macbook Pro, v12.1, using bash if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

I found my problem.

Deep in the recesses of my `.bash_profile` was the command

```
set -o vi
```

Which effectively made my prompt work like vi after it detected the `ESC` character from going back a word. After I removed the line, things work like I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with oh my zsh and the `zsh-vi-mode` plugin enabled. After disabling the plugin, Natural Text Editing works just fine.